# Product of eigenvalues over a finite field

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields

A have a matrix whose characteristic polynomial has 1 value over the ground field and 4 values over extension field. Let me call this matrix as P5. If I construct P25 as P5⨂P5, i.e, P25=P5⨂P5.

I notice that P25 characteristic polynomial has 9 eigenvalues over GF(5) and 16 in an extension field. But

[image]

Note that the product of eigenvalues by eigenvalues give us half of the values over ground field and other half in extension field.

This way I can predict that P25 has 1+8 = 9 values in the ground Field and 4+4+8=16 values over extension field.

The doubt is how can I prove that ExE produces half over Basis Field and half over Extension Field?? I tested with various matrices and 100% prediction was exact.

Comment: What are the **values** of a characteristic polynomial? The eigenvalues? i.e. the zeros of the characteristic polynomial? What do B and E stand for in your table?

Comment: I am trying to guess what might be happening. How often products of two eigenvalues of $P_5$ belong to the base field could heavily depend on how the characteristic polynomial of $P_5$ factors over the base field. If  you have a lot of quadratic factors, then the product of the roots of such a factor will automatically be in the base field. But if the characteristic polynomial has an irreducible quartic factor then it should not happen. Have you tested with a $P_5$ whose characteristi polynomial has an irreducible quartic as a factor?

Comment: Yes, values for me is the eigenvalues. B means Base Field, E means extension field. I know that when I do the product of eigenvalues in the Base (or Ground) Field the result is in the Ground Field and when I multiply values from the Ground Field with values in the extension Filed the result is on the extension field. But, when I multiply values in the extension field with values in the extension field the result can be in the ground or in the extension field. I noticed that when those values are the eigenvalues of a characteristic polynomial, half of then will lie in the ground.

Comment: Note the P25 is the Kronecker product of P5 by itself. This way, I know that eigenvalues of P25 are the product of the eigenvalues of P5.

Comment: If when factoring characteristic polynomial there appear an irreducible polynomial then its roots lies in an extension field. I can determine which extension field is by discovering to what expoent this polynomial belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Making an educated guess about what the asker is seeing. Consider the following matrix
$$
P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with entries viewed as elements of the field $GF(5)$. Because this matrix has a diagonal $1\times1$ block in the upper left, and the other diagonal $4\times4$ block is the companion matrix of the quartic
$$
f(x)=x^4+4x^3+x^2+1,
$$
we see that the characteristic polynomial of $P$ is
$\chi_P(x)=(x-1)f(x).$

I selected the polynomial $f(x)$ to be an irreducible factor of $(x^{39}-1)/(x^{13}-1)$ (in other words it is of exponent $39$). Therefore the zeros of $f(x)$ are roots of unity $\beta, \beta^5, \beta^{25},\beta^{125}=\beta^{8+3\cdot39}=\beta^8$ of order $39$.

The eigenvalues of $P\otimes P$ are then the pairwise products of eigenvalues of $P$. In other words, $1$, $\beta^{5^i}, i=0,1,2,3,$ (each with multiplicity two) and $\lambda_{i,j}:=\beta^{5^i+5^j}, 0\le i,j\le3$.
I claim that of those eigenvalues only $1$ belongs to the base field $GF(5)$.
Because $39$ is a factor of $624=5^4-1$ but is not a factor of $5^2-1$, the element $\beta$ generates the field $GF(5^4)$. The power $\beta^{13}$ is a cubic root of unity and thus belongs to $GF(5^2)$.

We can conclude that

- The second group of eigenvalues, $\beta^{5^i}$ are all in $GF(5^4)\setminus GF(5^2)$.
- The eigenvalue $\lambda_{0,0}=\beta^2$, as well as its conjugates $\lambda_{i,i},i=1,2,3$, is of order $39$, and thus also in $GF(5^4)\setminus GF(5^2)$.
- The double eigenvalue $\lambda_{1,0}=\lambda_{0,1}=\beta^6$ is of order $13$, and therefore belongs to $GF(5^4)\setminus GF(5^2)$. The same applies to the conjugates $\lambda_{i,j}$ with $i\equiv j\pm1\pmod4$.
- The double eigenvalue $\lambda_{2,0}=\lambda_{0,2}=\beta^{26}$ is of order $3$, and therefor belongs to $GF(5^2)\setminus GF(5)$. The same applies to the conjugates $\lambda_{i,j}$ with $i\equiv j+2\pmod4$.

So this seems to disprove your conjecture. Only a single eigenvalue in the base field. But:

- Your conjecture will hold, if the characteristic polynomial of $P$ has two irreducible quadratic factors. The product of the zeros of such a factor is in $GF(5)$.
- Even with an irreducible quartic factor you may get some extra eigenvalues in $GF(5)$. For example if a primitive root of unity of order thirteen $\gamma=\beta^3$ is an eigenvalue of $P$, then this gives as eigenvalues of $P\otimes P$ elements like $\gamma\cdot\gamma^{5^2}=1\in GF(5)$. I have not thought about how often this happens. It is related to the relative norm being surprisingly mapped down to the base field.

---

Please check the above claim for this chosen $P$. If you think that the conjecture holds for this $P$ as well, let me know!